# Calculating distance between geo points

Tags: java, gis

I am trying to find closest cluster to the given cluster 1 (see example below). To visualize clusters, I used QGIS (X axis is Longitude and Y axis is Latitude).

[image]

First of all I calculated centroids for each cluster. Thus I got the following results:

```
Cluster 1:
Lat : -83.5
Lon: -159.3

Cluster 2:
Lat: -80.5
Lon: -123.9

Cluster 3:
Lat: -83.4
Lon: 159.4
```

As a distance metric I use Haversine formula:

```
/**
 * Calculates Haversine distance between two points
 * @param lat1
 * @param lon1
 * @param lat2
 * @param lon2
 * @return
 */
private static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double R = 6372.8;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
 
    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2),2) + Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2),2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return R * c;
}
```

I got the following results (one can get similar results by running the `haversine` function):

- **Distance between Cluster 1 and 2: 628.37**
- **Distance between Cluster 1 and 3: 513.73**

So, though it's clear from the picture that Cluster 2 is closer to Cluster 1 than Cluster 3, the formula says that Cluster 3 is closer.
Which formula should I better use for this case?

Comment: formula is right, but your picture isn't

Comment: @Azat Nugusbayev: Why is there a problem with visualization? I used QGIS (X axis is Longitude and Y axis is Latitude).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Azat says, your picture is wrong.  For two reasons, actually.

Firstly, you've forgotten something very important - the "edges" of the map at +/- 180 degrees actually meet on the physical globe.  That is, you need to (at minimum) turn your picture into a cylinder, like some 2d video games do.

Secondly, you need to remember what makes calculating distances on a sphere via lat/long so tricky: as you near the north/south poles, identical longitude values will *get closer together*, while latitude values will stay the same distance apart.

If you plot these on a sphere properly, it should really look like this:
[image: Clusters]

(Courtesy of google earth)

The red line is about where the 180 degree latitude mark is (clusters 1 and 3 are almost reflections over that line).  **NOW** it's clear that Cluster 3 is closer to Cluster 1 than Cluster 2 is.

Answer (score 1):

All your calculation are totally exact.

You're really close to the south pole that why you make huge errors drawing points like if earth was flat.

Here is a pic from google earth where earth is round, we can see that *1* is closer to *3* than to *2* :

[image: position of centroids on round earth]

Comment: Well, if I run haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) and haversine(lat1,lon1,lat3,lon3), I get 628.37 and 513.73, accordingly, though visually centroid 3 is farther than centroid 2. Could you please elaborate your answer?